# Second monitor not working under Gnome (using Wayland)

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, nvidia, multi-monitor, wayland

I installed Arch Linux `4.15.9-1-ARCH` on a `Dell Inspiron 15 7000 (7577)` laptop that comes with and (1) an integrated `Intel HD Graphics 630 (Kaby Lake GT2) GPU` and (2) a discrete `NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile` GPU.

After all the paraphernalia of installing `base`, `base-devel`, and setting everything else according to the (super-awesome I have to say) **Installation Guide** from the Wiki, I also installed `gnome`. At this point I was expecting my second monitor, connected through the `HDMI 2.0` port, to come back from the afterlife...but it did not. So I checked the installed open-source video drivers (`pacman -Q | grep xf86`) and I didn't find anything. For what it's worth, at this point, whenever I executed `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` I was getting back `X11`.

So I went ahead and installed `nvidia`, `nvidia-settings`, and restarted! After that, whenever I execute `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`, it returns `wayland`...but still, my second monitor is *all black*.

I wonder if there is a way to use the discrete NVIDIA GPU under `Wayland` and make my second monitor come to life? (see below)

---

**IMPORTANT:** I'm using `gdm`. If I select only the `GNOME` option before login in, the system uses `wayland` and the integrated Intel GPU. If I select `GNOME on Xorg`, everything works fine (my second monitor works!) and the discrete NVIDIA GPU is used. I don't know if there is a "proper" way to know what GPU is being used...I figure this out going to the `About` section under `Settings`.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: Never. I know there is a way (of course, huh?!) because later on I installed Antergos and everything worked as expected. So I left that out since I knew I was going to need acres of configuration changes (and maybe something else) I didn't fully understand. I hope you have more luck.

Comment: Darn. Thanks for your response! I guess I'll keep looking for now.